# How to name a column while creating a data frame using a name stored in a variable?

Tags: r, dataframe

Trying to create a data.frame like this:

```
a = "foo"
bar = data.frame(a = 1:3)
```

But the name of the column is `a`, not `foo`:

```
> bar
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

The column can be renamed after creating data.frame, but how to easily assign it's name by a variable just in the same data.frame command?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `setNames()` function should work for you:

```
a <- "Numbers"
b <- "Letters"

bar <- setNames(data.frame(1:3, letters[1:3]), c(a, b))
bar
#   Numbers Letters
# 1       1       a
# 2       2       b
# 3       3       c
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for it. Do you have any idea how to do the task if we are making a data.frame of several tables or vectors and we want a few of them to be named by variables: data.frame(a = 1:3, b) while b is a table and we are not going to change the names of b columns?

Comment: @AliSharifi, when you write "*b is a table*", do you actually mean `table` or `data.frame`? If `b` is a `data.frame`, you could just use `setNames(data.frame(1:3, b), c(a, names(b)))` (if I understood your question correctly).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do what you want to do here because of the way R is interpreting the argument names you supply. Effectively you want `get(a) = 1:3` as you want R to take the value of the object stored as `a` rather than the label `a` itself, but that idiom is not allowed here.

I would do this:

```
> a <- "foo"
> bar <- data.frame(1:3)
> names(bar) <- a
> 
> bar
  foo
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

Comment: Thanks, I already know this solution. I am looking for a one-line command to do it!

Comment: If you insist: `bar <- \`names<-\`(data.frame(1:3),a)`

Comment: @BlueMagister Neat but I **really** don't recommend this (& I get the impression you don't either?!)

Comment: @AliSharifi Don't always be on the look-out for a one-liner. Two are just as useful and easier to write. Think about how much time you have spent on this to save a single R call?

Comment: @BlueMagister: Great! Why don't you make it as an answer such that I can approve and every one can see? Also would you please make a line of description what does your command really mean, in the answer?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Thanks. Many R problems are like puzzles to me and I enjoy to solve them, for the sake of creativity!

Comment: @GavinSimpson, there is, of course the "convenience function" `setNames()`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I'm a bit way of using `\`names<-\``, but I'm not sure why it's not recommended.

Comment: Mainly because you really need to understand R to know what is going on in that call. The two lines I show are easy to understand the meaning of, but when cast to a one-liner in the manner you show you do have to think a bit more to grep the intention. So whilst nothing wrong with the code, the meaning is obfuscated to some degree. `setNames()` would be better for a one-liner and I see someone has now posted that as an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
a = structure(data.frame(1:3), names="foo")
> a
foo
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification of [Daniel Gerlanc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801638/how-to-name-a-column-while-creating-a-data-frame-using-a-name-stored-in-a-variab/12811638#12811638) using chaining

```
a <- "foo"
a <- data.frame(1:3) %>% structure(names = c(a))

  foo
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

Chaining is useful when you are creating a data frame from another data type, for example a zoo series,

```
a <- c("foo","data")
bar
2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05 
      0.78       0.46       0.82       1.07       1.04


a <- bar %>% as.data.frame() %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% structure(names=a)

          foo data
1  2016-01-01 0.78
2  2016-01-02 0.46
3  2016-01-03 0.82
4  2016-01-04 1.07
5  2016-01-05 1.04
```